# Angular: Cannot find control with name: 'date'

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am creating a form where a user select date and fill the form and subimit the form,  here is what I have .  for reference I am using  [igx-calendar](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/calendar.html#calendar-demo)

calendar component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef, Input, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IgxCalendarComponent, IgxDialogComponent } from 'igniteui-angular';
import {  NgModel, FormControl, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => CalendarComponent), multi: true }
  ]
})
export class CalendarComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
  @ViewChild('calendar') public calendar: IgxCalendarComponent;
  @ViewChild('alert') public dialog: IgxDialogComponent;
  @Input()
  label: string;


  private _theDate: string;

  constructor() { }

  propagateChange = (_: any) => { };
  onTouched: any = () => { };

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    console.log('writeValue => obj : ', obj);
    if (obj) {
      this._theDate = obj;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
    console.log('registerOnChange => fn : ', fn);
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
    console.log('registerOnTouched => fn : ', fn);
  }

  get theDate() {
    console.log('get theDate()');
    return this._theDate;
  }

  set theDate(val) {
    console.log('set theDate(val) - val => ', val);
    this._theDate = val;
    this.propagateChange(val);
  }
  public verifyRange(dates: Date[]) {
    if (dates.length > 5) {
      this.calendar.selectDate(dates[0]);
      this.dialog.open();
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

calender.html

```
<div class="sample-wrapper">
    <div class="sample-content">
        <!-- Single selection mode -->
        <article class="sample-column calendar-wrapper">
            <igx-calendar></igx-calendar>
        </article>

    </div>
</div>
```

Booking.component.ts **UPDATE**

```
export class BookingComponent implements OnInit {

  comments: {};
  addcomments: Comment[];
  angForm: FormGroup;
  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  validEmail = false;

  constructor(private flashMessages: FlashMessagesService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private activeRouter: ActivatedRoute,
    private moviesService: MoviesService) {
    this.comments = [];
    this.createForm();
    }
  onChange(newValue) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    const validEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if (validEmail.test(newValue)) {
      this.validEmail = true;
    } else {
      this.validEmail = false;
    }

  }

  createForm() {
    this.angForm = this.fb.group({
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email])
    });
  }
  addReview(date, email, city, hotel) {
    this.moviesService.addReview(date, email, city, hotel).subscribe(success => {
      this.flashMessages.show('You are data we succesfully submitted', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
      // get the id
      this.activeRouter.params.subscribe((params) => {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
        let id = params['id'];
        this.moviesService.getComments(id)
          .subscribe(comments => {
            console.log(comments);
            this.comments = comments;
          });
      });
    }, error => {
      this.flashMessages.show('Something went wrong', { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000 });
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Booking.component.html

```
<div class="row about-booking">
    <flash-messages></flash-messages>
    <form [formGroup]="angForm" class="form-element">
      <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-2 about-booking_calendar">
        <div class="form-group form-element_date">
          <app-calendar formControlName="date" [(ngModel)]="theDate" #date></app-calendar> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 about-booking_form">
        <div class="form-group form-element_email">
          <input type="email" class="form-control info" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" #email (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['email'].invalid && (angForm.controls['email'].dirty || angForm.controls['email'].touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['email'].errors.required">
            Email is required.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3 form-element_city">
          <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" #cityName>
            <option selected *ngFor="let city of cities" [ngValue]="city.name">{{city.name}}</option>

          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3 form-element_hotel">
          <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" #hotelName>
            <option selected *ngFor="let hotel of hotels" [ngValue]="hotel.name">{{hotel.name}}</option>

          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" (click)="addReview(date.value, email.value, cityName.value , hotelName.value)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block form-element_btn"
            [disabled]="!validEmail">Book</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

when I submit the data I get the following error:

> BookingComponent.html:59 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name:
>   'date'

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Try with name=date or declare a control with name date

Comment: Where have you created `angForm`? it should have a `FormControl` for `date` if you are referencing the same using `formControlName="date"`. Use either `[(ngModel)]` or reactive form approach, do not mix both.

Comment: Hii @sabithpocker check the update , I forgot to add the booking .ts , now added

Comment: @PrashantPimpale that didnt help , :(

Comment: you haven't defined date anywhere in the Form Group ...

Comment: That is what i comment to declare a control with `name`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

in your createForm() function you didn't add the date FormControl

```
createForm() {
  this.angForm = this.fb.group({
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    date: new FormControl('') // this line missing in your code
  });
}
```

you shouldn't use both ngModel (template driven forms) and formControlName (reactive forms) in the same input.

Comment: Thanks for help now no that error, i have another simple error, bad request, here i have a fiddle for backend and service I used, can you check it why I get Bad Request  https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/asq9Lnjf/4/

Answer (score 6):

In my case I was getting this same error for all the fields in the FormGroup, the reason was the data from server was **NOT** received and the html UI code attempted to executed the reactive form and hence the error. So to solve this issue I had to use the *ngIf condition on the form element and stopped the rendering of the form until the server response was completed.

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" *ngIf="userProfile != undefined">
```

Comment: Great Catch.  I tried using different angular lifecycles and I wasn't having much luck.